# Javascript confirm method

Tags: javascript

I have added a confirm box that works when user refreshes page, and when user tries to navigate away from the current page. But I want it to do so that it cancels the operation of going away from the page. I'm not sure how to implement this.

Another problem that I have, is that this code only works in EI, and not in Firefox or Chrome. Normally it is the other way round. But maybe I should post the browser issue as a separate post?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Verify</title>       
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleRequest() {
                if(confirm('Sure you want to quit?')) {
                //  redirect or quit;
                } else {
                    //Do not change page or quit 
                }
            }
        </script>

    <body onunload="handleRequest()">

        <p></p>
        <p>Body content</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onbeforeunload`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

It will open dialogbox and ask user stay or go away from page. It's native browser behavior.

Comment: How would you use this in the <body> tag?

Comment: @user1960836 There is no need in that. Just place this code in the `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can only cancel it with onbeforeunload, and by returning false to the event :

```
<body onbeforeunload="return confirm('Sure you want to quit?');">
```

Comment: So you would just return false in the else statement to cancel?